# How do I set a variable as a color with the askcolor widget?

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to make a paint type program in which you can draw multiple different shapes, and I am trying to change the color of the shape I am drawing using a color picker.  I don't understand how to do this.

I just started coding one week ago and know no ways of trouble shooting, but I have tried adding different variables set as the chosen color.

```
def getColor():
    color = askcolor() 

def line():
    a = (asl.get())
    b = (bsl.get())
    c = (csl.get())
    d = (dsl.get())
    fill = color
    cnv.create_line(a, b, c, d)

def rect():
    a = (asl.get())
    b = (bsl.get())
    c = (csl.get())
    d = (dsl.get())
    fill = color
    cnv.create_rectangle(a, b, c, d)

def circ():#center coordinates, radius
    a = (asl.get())
    b = (bsl.get())
    c = (csl.get())
    d = (dsl.get())
    fill = color
    cnv.create_oval(a, b, c, d)

from tkinter import *

from tkinter.colorchooser import *

cp=Tk()

cnv=Canvas(cp, width = 600, height = 600, bg = 'white')
cnv.grid(row = 2, column = 5, padx = 3, pady = 3)

#this is the control panel for the shape maker
exitbtn=Button(cp, text = 'Exit', command = exit)
exitbtn.grid(row = 0, column = 1, padx = 3, pady = 3)

linebtn=Button(cp, text = 'line', command = line)
linebtn.grid(row = 0, column = 2, padx = 3, pady = 3)

rectbtn=Button(cp, text = 'Rectangle', command = rect)
rectbtn.grid(row = 0, column = 3, padx = 3, pady = 3)

circbtn=Button(cp, text = 'Circle', command = circ)
circbtn.grid(row = 0, column = 4, padx = 3, pady = 3)

colrbtn=Button(cp, text = 'Color', command = getColor)
colrbtn.grid(row = 0, column = 5, padx = 3, pady = 3)


#changes the x amd y values for the corners of the shape
asl = Scale(cp, from_=0, to=600, length = 200, tickinterval=50)
asl.set(0)
asl.grid(row=6, column=1, padx=3,pady=3)

bsl = Scale(cp, from_=0, to=600, length = 200)
bsl.set(0)
bsl.grid(row=6, column=2, padx=3,pady=3)

csl = Scale(cp, from_=0, to=600, length = 200)
csl.set(0)
csl.grid(row=6, column=3, padx=3,pady=3)

dsl = Scale(cp, from_=0, to=600, length = 200)
dsl.set(0)
dsl.grid(row=6, column=4, padx=3,pady=3)


#labels that tell what the sliders do
x1 = Label(cp, text="x1")
x1.grid(row=5, column=1, padx=3,pady=3)

y1 = Label(cp, text="y1")
y1.grid(row=5, column=2, padx=3,pady=3)

x2 = Label(cp, text="x2")
x2.grid(row=5, column=3, padx=3,pady=3)

y2 = Label(cp, text="y2")
y2.grid(row=5, column=4, padx=3,pady=3)

mainloop()
```

I expected it to use the hex value as a variable and fill the shape with my chosen color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define `color` as a global variable in any function that sets it. `global` means that the variable is available everywhere within the file.

The first step is to modify `getColor` to include a `global` statement. Also, it's important to know that `askcolor` returns a tuple, with the second value being a color specification you can use when creating canvas items. That is the value that should be saved

```
def getColor():
    global color
    color = askcolor()[1]
```

The next step is to modify your functions to use this when creating the object. For example, your `rect` function might look like this:

```
def rect():
    a = (asl.get())
    b = (bsl.get())
    c = (csl.get())
    d = (dsl.get())
    cnv.create_rectangle(a, b, c, d, fill=color)
```